# Normalized smoothing with a kernel

Tags: python, numpy, kernel, convolution, smoothing

I am trying to smooth a noisy one-dimensional physical signal, `y`, while retaining correspondence between the signal's amplitude and its units. I'm applying a Gaussian kernel and normalizing the Gaussian itself  based on its own integral.

```
import numpy.random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

#Gaussian kernel (not normalized here)
def gaussian(x, sigma):
    return np.exp(-(x/sigma)**2/2) 

#convolution
def smooth(y,box_pts): 
    x = (np.linspace(-box_pts/2.,box_pts/2.,box_pts + 1)) #Gaussian centred on 0
    std_norm = 3. #3. is an arbitrary value for normalizing the sigma
    sigma = box_pts/std_norm 
    integral = quad(gaussian, x[0], x[-1], args=(sigma))[0]
    box = gaussian(x, sigma)/integral
    y_smooth = np.convolve(y,box,mode='same')
    return y_smooth

box_size = 10
length = 100
y = numpy.random.randn(length)
y_smooth = smooth(y,box_size)
plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
plt.plot(y_smooth)
plt.show()
```

In this example, `y` is the signal I want to smooth, `box_pts` is the width or region over which the Gaussian kernel is applied as it is translated. And to normalize my convolution, I've simply divided by the integral of the Gaussian by itself. Since the Gaussian has a certain width (given by `box_pts`) and is zero outside of this interval compared to the physical axis of `y`, I am normalizing the Gaussian to the region over which it is non-zero as opposed to $-\infty$ to $ \infty$. This method appears simple enough and the normalization appears to work, but is dividing by the kernel's integral itself the "right"  or suggested approach to take when normalizing convolutions/kernels?

Based on a simple example, it appears keep the integral about the same, but amplitudes are no longer consistent as visualized below which is a bit problematic as I want to retain a smoothed signal while removing the noise:

Original:

[image: Raw data]

Smoothed:

[image: Smoothed data]

I get improved amplitudes when I decrease `box_size` relative to `length`, but this keeps the signal noisy. Decreasing `std_norm` also appears to help reduce noise, but this influences the amplitude. My question boils down to deciding how one chooses optimal `std_norm` and `box_norm` for a given noisy signal `y` of size `length` such that I can reduce the noise while keeping the output physically sound (i.e. smoothed signal amplitude is somewhat consistent with the original signal and the integral under the smoothed curve is fairly similar, too). I have applied a Gaussian kernel here, but am interested in hopefully a general approach for any arbitrary kernel.

Comment: Convolution with a Gaussian window is a low-pass filter.  It will naturally remove high frequency components of your signal.  It looks like your signal has some large amplitude high frequency components, and these are being removed by the filter.  If that is not what you want, you might have to think more carefully about what you mean when you say you want to "smooth" your noisy signal, and what sort of output you expect for that example.

Comment: By the way, here's a check of your scaling.  Suppose the input `y` contains all ones.  You probably expect the output to be all ones.  With your current code, you get the value 1.04148023; i.e. your scaling is not quite right.  Instead of using the integral, use `box = gaussian(x, sigma);  box = box / box.sum()`.  (That is, you have already discretized the function, so to normalize the values, just divide by the sum of the values.)  Alternatively, consider using [`scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter1d.html).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thank you for the explanation and comments. Yes, carefully considering the type of filter for my purpose will be necessary. As this is a general problem and I am not the first to ask it, if you have any references for convolution kernels commonly employed for different types of filters (e.g. preserve amplitudes), that would be greatly appreciated.